# Xpath - remove duplicate and sorted distinct list

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using a Excel FILTERXML function to return a distinct list.

The formula is :

```
=FILTERXML(StudentList,"//b[not(preceding::*=.)]")
```

I create a define name called "`StudentList`" for the `xml`

The `xml` is like this:

```
<a>
 <b>Sam</b>
 <b>Tim</b>
 <b>Max</b>
 <b>Ronny</b>
 <b>Rhea</b>
 <b>Sam</b>
 <b>Tim</b>
 <b>Joan</b>
 <b>Peter</b>
 <b>Eric</b>
 <b>Ronny</b>
 <b>Sam</b>
 <b>Julie</b>
 <b>Max</b>
</a>
```

This Xpath I use only can remove duplicate from left to right without sorting:

```
//b[not(preceding::*=.)]
```

and, the formula unsorted result was :

```
{"Sam";"Tim";"Max";"Ronny";"Rhea";"Joan";"Peter";"Eric";"Julie"}
```

What I want is a sorting result, the target is :

```
{"Eric";"Joan";"Julie";"Max";"Peter";"Rhea";"Ronny";"Sam";"Tim"}
```

How to modify the Xpath to meet my target.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What environment / programming language do you use XPath in? Please show the code that produces the result you are showing. Thanks. Hint for the answer: XPath is not the right tool for sorting. Use your host programming language.

Comment: @ Mathias Müller, I am using Excel formula, the formula is : Define name of the xml in a name called "StudentList", then enter the formula : =FILTERXML(StudentList,"//b[not(preceding::*=.)]"), it will return a unsorted remove duplicate list as in : {"Sam";"Tim";"Max";"Ronny";"Rhea";"Joan";"Peter";"Eric";"Julie"}, but I wanted a sorted list. Thanks

Comment: @Mathias Müller, In fact the XPATH can sort Numeric value,  but I am looking a way to sort the Text value using XPATH. Thanks

Comment: Think about how to achieve your goal, rather than how to do it with a specific tool that might not be the best fit. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Can Excel sort the results?

Comment: @bosco_yip XPath 1.0 cannot sort. Also, grouping (deduplicating) and sorting can be done in Excel

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve this by using the Excel SORT function on the oustide.

```
    =SORT(FILTERXML(StudentList,"//b[not(preceding::*=.)]"))
```